# How to make sure that email has been sent in android using ACTION_SEND?

Tags: android, email, android-intent

**This is the code to send mail. But How will we get back result saying sent successfully ?**

```
public static void sendFeedback(Context paramContext) {
    Intent localIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    localIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"xyz@mm.com"});
    localIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC, "");
    String str = null;
    try {
        str = paramContext.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(paramContext.getPackageName(), 0).versionName;
        localIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "App");

        localIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
        paramContext.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(localIntent, "Choose an Email client :"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("OpenFeedback", e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: you will not get any confirmation from another app. As you have fired an intent to choose application that supports to send email if there exists any

Comment: no way to check unfortunately, since email app does not have to confirm it.

Comment: Thank you @Damian Kozlak  Ankush Bist Vlad Matvienko and Hitesh Sahu